# Performance issue in oracle coherence cache using LikeFilter wildcard search

Tags: oracle-coherence

I have implemented wildcard search using oracle coherence API. When I execute the search on string fields(four fields) using 
1) "LikeFilter" with "fIgnoreCase" as true and 
2) search text is % patterns(eg: "%test%") and 
3) accumulated those using " AnyFilter",  and 
4) the volume of data in the cache is huge then the searches become very slow.

Applying the standard index does not have any effect on the performance, as it appears that this index works only for exact matches or comparisons.

Is there any special type of index in Coherence for wildcard searches (similar to the new indexes in Oracle TEXT)?   If not, is there any other way to improve wildcard query performance on Coherence, with large data sets in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide code snippet to understand the current solution applied. Also, hope following practices already applied:

1. Explain plan to see the query performance
2. Leveraging data-grid wide execution for parallel processing considering volume of data

Also, need information on volume of data (in GB) along with Coherence setup in place (no. of nodes, size of each node) to understand sizing of the cluster.